# How can I convert a std::basic_string type to an array of char type?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I get the following error when this code is run:

```
syslog(LOG_ERR | LOG_USER, "%s",errorString);
```

> cannot convert ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for >argument ‘2’ to ‘void syslog(int, const char*, ...)’   inServer.cpp    /PeCounter
>   line 478   C/C++ Problem

I am daemonizing the program and the errorString value prints just fine when outputted to stdio using cout, but it will not print when using a syslog call.

Any way to get std::basic_string(char) into the form of 'const char'.

Comment: Submitting your own answer is perfectly acceptable here. You don't need to include it in your question, even with a later edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that `std::basic_string` has an item access method `c_str()` which seems to fix the compiling issue.

Here is a site with more information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 6):

The `c_str()` or `data()` member function provides a pointer to the first element of an array of `char_type` which contains your string. It's valid as long as the string object itself remains valid and unchanged (but beware that operations that may cause reallocations may invalidate the pointer -- best not to store it).

Comment: Only `c_str()` guarantees a terminator at the end of the string.  `data()` may point to an unterminated copy of the string, which is dangerous for most APIs that are expecting a `const char *`.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Depends on the version of C++ you are using. In C++11 `data()` is nul-terminated as well (and guaranteed to be valid even on empty strings). So in C++11 the only difference between `c_str()` and `data()` really is the const-ness.

Comment: @Matthieu M.:  You're right--I was looking at the previous version of the spec.  Still, there are a lot of people using old libraries, so the distinction might be important.  Also `c_str()` is a little more suggestive of the intent.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Yes, the distinction really is important. Both the non nul-terminated and the "undefined" if empty aspects! The C++03 spec left more margin for implementation, but in doing so it made it opened more undefined holes.