# std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'char*' in assignment|

Tags: c++, codeblocks

tried to open a .cpp in code::blocks. Got few lines of error

Partial code :

```
void QSort(string List[], int Left, int Right)
{
  int i, j;
  char *x;
  string TEMP;

  i = Left;
  j = Right;
  x = List[(Left+Right)/2];

  do {
    while((strcmp(List[i],x) < 0) && (i < Right)) {
       i++;
    }
    while((strcmp(List[j],x) > 0) && (j > Left)) {
        j--;
    }
    if(i <= j) {
      strcpy(TEMP, List[i]);
      strcpy(List[i], List[j]);
      strcpy(List[j], TEMP);
      i++;
      j--;
   }
  } while(i <= j);

  if(Left < j) {
     QSort(List, Left, j);
  }
  if(i < Right) {
     QSort(List, i, Right);
  }
}
```

I recieve this error in line

```
 x = List[(Left+Right)/2];
```

> cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'char*'
>   in assignment|

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a std::basic\_string type to an array of char type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978201/how-can-i-convert-a-stdbasic-string-type-to-an-array-of-char-type)

Comment: Why not use the [lexicographical comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) operators for `std::string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they're incompatible. You need to call a member of `std::string` which returns a `const char*`.

```
x = List[(Left+Right)/2].c_str();
```

Be aware: this pointer is only valid for the life time of the std::string or until you modify the string object.

This function returns a `const char*` so you'll need to change the definition of `x` from `char*` to `const char*.

```
const char* x;
```

or better still, remove that line, and combine the two

```
void QSort(string List[], int Left, int Right)
{
    string TEMP;

    int i = Left;
    int j = Right;
    const char* x = List[(Left+Right)/2];
```

Infact, here's a rewrite that uses standard C++ algorithms throughout (std::string::compare instead of strcmp). This may make it easier for you to focus on the algorithm itself.

```
void QSort(string List[], int Left, int Right)
{
    int i = Left;
    int j = Right;
    const int mid = (Left+Right) / 2;

    for (;;) // repeat until we break.
    {
        // write both comparisons in terms of operator <
        while (List[i].compare(List[mid]) < 0 && i < Right)
            ++i;
        while (List[mid].compare(List[j]) < 0 && Left < j)
            --j;
        // if i == j then we reached an impasse.
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        std::swap(List[i], List[j]);
    }

  if(Left < j)
    QSort(List, Left, j);

  if(i < Right)
    QSort(List, i, Right);
}
```

Comment: I think is compiler issue, many lines of code affected.. any other solution?

Comment: It's not a compiler issue. You can't convert a `std::string` to a `const char*` because they are incompatible. You need to call the `c_str()` method of string to get the `const char*` which the std::string is managing.

Comment: Don't let the name, `string`, confuse you: `std::string` is a class name. `char foo[] = "hello";` and `char* foo = "hello";` are C-style strings, while `std::string foo = "hello";` is a different beast entirely.

Comment: `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*` - the const indicating "you can't modify the thing the pointer points to". You just need to change `x` from `char* x;` to `const char* x;`. Infact, remove the `char *x;` line and make the change shown above.

Comment: Take a look at my cleanup of the algorithm which avoids using char*-related functions entirely and uses the std::string member functions to do the compares.